# How to create named object with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

Working on getting some interfaces setup for my angular2 service using typescript.  Running into an issue of configuration.

I'd like to be able to access my data like this `myItem['chickens']` & get back the following object:

```
{
  name:"chicken",
  price:1000,
  names:["Harry", "Barry", "Larry"]
}
```

**How do I write my interface the correct way so that I can get my data back as previously mentioned?**

```
export interface StoreItem {
      itemName:{
        itemName: string;
        price: number;
        nameList: Array<string>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is it `myItem: StoreItem`?

Answer (score 5):

Your `StoreItem`s have string keys and typed values, so you could do:

```
interface StoreItem {
  [key: string]: {
    itemName: string;
    price: number;
    nameList: Array<string>;  // or string[]
  }
}
```

This would happily allow e.g.:

```
let myItem: StoreItem = {
  chickens: {
    name: 'chicken',
    price: 1000,
    names: ['Harry', 'Barry', 'Larry']
  }
};
```

And you can access that inner item either as `myItem['chickens']` or simply `myItem.chickens`.